# LyX disables all menus after upgrade to 15.04

Tags: upgrade, software-installation, latex, lyx

After upgrading to Ubuntu 15.04, I have a bug that drives my furious. LyX - the document processor - disables all menu items in the top panel. I already removed the `.lyx` directory in `~` and reconfigured the software but it still fails. You can see a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoVp6.png) of my problem.

Thanks, for your help !

Answer (score 0):

It was annoying me as well and surprisingly I had to search more than usual for a solution. I got the best solutions from [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-appmenu/+bug/1430059).

**tl;dr**
the real solution comes from installing `indicator-appmenu` from the proposed repository:

- [add proposed repository](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed), there is an option to use only selected packages if you want.
- `sudo apt-get install indicator-appmenu/vivid-proposed`

simple workarounds:

- press alt then write 'settings' once in lyx.
- Another option is to run lyx this way:

  ```
  QT_X11_NO_NATIVE_MENUBAR=1 lyx
  ```